# Shalln't vs. Shan't in British English

Tags: british-english, orthography, contractions, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I am a British English speaker and often use "shall" and "shall not". When I contract "shall not", I pronounce it [ʃɑlnt] -- that is, the "l" sound remains. My question, therefore, is how do I spell it?

I would naturally spell it as "shaln't". I see on Wiktionary that "shalln't" (with two "l"s) is listed as an archaic spelling and shouldn't be used. All other resources I've found indicate that it should be "shan't" -- with no "l" -- but this is the American English pronunciation, to me.

Comment: I've never heard your version (retaining the l-sound), nor seen any previous attempt to write it. I live near Manchester but travel fairly extensively around the UK. Is that pronunciation common where you live?

Comment: I think so, yes. To be honest, I've never really noticed, but no one looks at me funny when I say it. Presumably, if you've got a northern BE accent, it gets closer to [ʃænt]: The front vowel may then make the [l] much harder to pronounce, so it just gets dropped.

Comment: I've never heard it pronounced that way either...

Comment: Like Edwin and Elendil, I have never heard that pronunciation either. I would always and exclusively pronounce the contracted negative of _shall_ as [ʃɑːnt] with ne’er a trace of an l anywhere (relatively generic RP here). I consider the contraction itself very British—in AmE, I wouldn’t use it at all, l or no l; I’d say _won’t_ instead. If J.K. Rowling is to be believed, _shan’t_ is also the form used in Surrey.

Comment: (From the UK) I don't believe I've ever come across a spelling other than *shan't* or a pronunciation that has an 'l' sound in it. What struck me about the question was that a British English speaker appears to be equating spelling with pronunciation.

Comment: Looks like I'm the freak ;) @Rupe Point taken regarding orthography vs. phonology! I guess I'm surprised that "shalln't" is listed as archaic, as it would serve my purpose when "shan't" sounds wrong to me.

Comment: "Shall" and "shall not" (in any form) are pretty much restricted to explicit speech and formal writing in North American English now (the "will" future marker has almost completely displaced it in common usage). In explicit use, the *not* is stressed, so it's rarely heard as a contraction except as an affectation.

Comment: @Xophmeister: Given you seem to be the only person in the country who pronounces an /l/ in "**shan't**", I wouldn't worry too much about what sounds right or wrong to you. You should spend more time taking notice of what *other* people say! :)

Comment: I'm an American and only when my spell checker underlined shalnt did I realize it wasn't a word. So you're not the only one that pronounces it that way. To me, shant is a distinct word, even though it means the same

Comment: @Xophmeister I just noticed an oddity in the question and your first comment. Are you saying that you pronounce it with the low back vowel /ɑ/ (as in _heart_), followed by an /l/? Because that is phonotactically impossible in English, unless the underlying form is /arl/ (as in _Marlboro_ [ˡmɑːlbərə]), and then it's always long. [ɑl] is, at least to me, utterly nonexistent and impossible. The front vowel in [ʃant] up north wouldn't be likely to make the /l/ harder to pronounce—quite the opposite, in fact: that's the vowel also found in the non-negated _shall_ [ʃal].

Answer (score 1):

The spelling with the l sound is "shalln't". Also, I came across this after I heard it in Stargate SG1.

Season 9 - Episode 4 "The Ties that Bind". About 25 minutes in.

Daniel Jackson is told something along the lines of "we shall have to get used to each other". And he replies "No, we shalln't".

Also, iOS autocorrect will automatically punctuate "shalln't" for you.

Comment: Perhaps also point out that English orthography doesn't generally reflect pronunciation particularly well.